# Elasticsearch in microservices architecture, design question

Tags: elasticsearch, microservices

I am designing a system, where I have several microservices communicating via middleware.

Now, every blueprint about microservices underlines that microservices must be autonomous and each of them must handle their own data. Currently, each microservice in my system does store data in a relational database.

I have a new requirement to implement a full-text search, each of my microservices is storing possibly searchable entities.

I was thinking to use an ElasticSearch cluster, where I'd have several indexes, indexes would serve as boundaries that separate the data which comes from various micro-services. I would like to underscore the fact that I plan to use ES only as a search engine, not as a system of record.

*Here is my dilemma:
1. Should I allow each microservice to handle ES interactions directly (as caching and persistence)? 2. Or should I create a separate microservice (let's call it "search"), which would be the one that interacts with the ES cluster?
I am leaning towards 1. b/c since each microservice has to be autonomous in persistence, caching, it can also handle full-text searches too.*

It will be interesting to hear out different opinions.

---

UPDATE:

Here is why I think each microservice should handle their searches individually:

1. To me, a full-text search capability is similar to persistence and caching layers, each micro-service knows better the business model and is responsible for implementing those layers individually.
2. If I introduce one more microservice just for doing searches, I'll have one extra possible point of failure, same goes to using PubSub as a middleman if we do not want direct interaction between `search` microservice and the rest of the pack.
   On the contrary, using ES directly, which is a highly-available SaaS, eliminates single point of failure.
   All write requests will be fast and there will be no lag. Information will be searchable right away. This will guarantee a seamless user experience.
3. I do not see search as another business process (maybe my understanding is flawed). To me, it is just a nice-to-have feature, not part of core functionality. However, once implemented, I want it to provide a great user experience.

This model of having an individual `search` microservice reminds of CQRS (command query responsibility segregation) architectural pattern. Where I'd first push the data to DB in my microservice A, then publish it to the messaging broker (command), a message would be picked up from the queue by the consumer and pushed into ES. Then frontend, on the read path (query), would go directly to `search` microservice.

I have never seen this pattern implemented for searching, it makes sense to do it in a big data world, where one microservice would ingest the data, then the worker process aggregates it for analytics and pushes it into an aggregated data table or separate data store and only then the data will become queryable via separate micro-service, that is enabling fetching of the analytics data.

Are there any publications out there or successful implementations of the CQRS pattern for ES (taking to consideration that ES is not used as a primary system of record but as a full-text search engine)?

Comment: In the same boat. What did you end up doing? How are you finding it so far? Any learning to share?

Answer (score 1):

Another search service would be overly abstracting it.

What I would do:

1. Use Xpack Security RBAC, which is now free, to lock down the indices for each micro service to an account that the service is configured to use: https://www.elastic.co/blog/security-for-elasticsearch-is-now-free
2. Use search templates in Elasticsearch to abstract out the search logic from the services, to ES, then have the services call the templates.

Comment: I was thinking to build a common search library, which would facilitate ES searches for my microservices. 
I am not so sure about search templates.

Comment: I think I will be using `Spring Data Elasticsearch` instead of writing my own common lib.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a separate `Search` service. There are several reasons for that.

1. It's another (business) process so you can be more flexible. Let's say you might have `CustomerMasterData` service and `CustomerAddress` service. But search requirements are to be able to search either by customer name or by address. Having two different Servers/ES indexes will not make you life easier. However in case of separate search service you can actually build index that holds data from different sources.
2. Service should own data. It means that `Search` should be the only service that has access to the ES index directly.
3. Filling ES index could be separated and done via communication to another service. I would do it via messaging system. For instance `Search` service sends `Sync` request and other services that listen to the queue will send out data. It allows to keep things independent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, see UPDATE section in the question. This is mainly my response to your post. I would like to hear out your further thoughts.

Comment: @rkm : I wondering about point 3 i.e if DDB streams from other microservices should be directly writing to ES indexes vs using messaging system to relay the message and write from a lambda with in the ESsevrice. especially since there is a pretty straightforward lib to do it: https://github.com/matrus2/dynamodb-stream-elasticsearch . Wondering if I should add additional SNS and lambda just for that